# How to find out from the Windows registry where IE is installed?

Tags: internet-explorer, registry

I can find out where Firefox is installed as follows; query this key to get the current version:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox
    CurrentVersion
```

... then query this key to get the installed path (where "nnn" is the version number obtained above):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox\nnn\Main
    Install Directory
```

But I can't work out how to find where IE is installed. What key or keys will work on Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, and later?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\IEXPLORE.EXE
```

Comment: Works in Win 7 and Win XP and invulnerable to localisation issues.

Answer (score 3):

IE is included in Windows Features. Every windows operating system (XP and later) have IE installed by default. And the installation directory is always:

```
%PROGRAMFILES%\Internet Explorer
```

Comment: Is there any risk of this path being localized?

Answer (score -3):

try out this:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Microsoft > InternetExplorer > Version Vector
```

There you can find IE version

Hope this will help you

-Saligh

Comment: Sorry, I'm after the installed location, not the version number.